# ssh on environment variables on remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh, .bash-profile

how to export environment variables to the remote machine to the specific user.

I am using below command to do export but the echo is returning empty.

I thought to approach in another way by explicitly moving this variable to .bashrc but even that approach is failed.

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$ip -n "sudo -u  rahul -i  'export DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV='"'devops'"'' echo $DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV"
```

approach i followed to explicitly write to .bashrc

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$ip -n "sudo -u  rahul -i 'echo -n 'DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV=devops' >> .bashrc"
```

one drawback i see here in 2nd approach is that i have to write if condition to check env is set or not.

The reason i am ssh  into ubuntu first because i am writing the script to get execute by Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I have to point out which I assume you are aware of but nevertheless:

1. In the first line there is one single quote that I believe is redundant or is misplaced.

```
sudo -u rahul -i 'export DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV='"'devops'"'' echo $DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV
                                                           ^
```

2. Multiple command execution is supposed to be separated with `;` or with an operator like `&&` or `||`

Having these in mind I've tested the following command and it works for me:

```
sudo -H -u rahul bash -c 'export DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV=devops; echo $DEVOPS_TOOLS_DEST_ENV'
```

Note that I've changed the way the command is executed by specifying the shell: `bash`.
I've set the HOME variable to the **rahul**'s home dir using `-H`.
I've also removed the quotes all together and separated the commands accordingly.

I hope this helps. Cheers!